# How can I get data from python generator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, generator

This is a function that use the keyword yield。

I wanna get real data from the function。

How Can I do that?

```
"""
    # function to reshape features into (samples, time steps, features)

    Only sequences that meet the window-length are considered, no padding is used.
    This means for testing we need to drop those which are below the window-length.
    An alternative would be to pad sequences so that we can use shorter ones
"""
def gen_sequence(samples, seq_length, seq_cols):
    # for one id I put all the rows in a single matrix
    data_matrix = samples[seq_cols].values
    num_elements = data_matrix.shape[0]
    # Iterate over two lists in parallel.
    # For example id1 have 192 rows and sequence_length is equal to 50
    # so zip iterate over two following list of numbers (0,112),(50,192)
    # 0 50 -> from row 0 to row 50
    # 1 51 -> from row 1 to row 51
    # 2 52 -> from row 2 to row 52
    # ...
    # 111 191 -> from row 111 to 191

    for start, stop in zip(range(0, num_elements-seq_length), range(seq_length, num_elements)):
        yield data_matrix[start:stop, :]
```

this is what i do,but I only get a list of []

```
  # samples, seq_length, seq_cols
    # generator for the sequences
    seq_gen = []
    for serial_number in hdd['serial_number'].unique():
        temp = gen_sequence(hdd[hdd['serial_number']==serial_number], sequence_length, sequence_cols)
        print(type(temp))
        seq_gen.append(list(temp))
    # print(seq_gen)
```

the example of dataframe hdd

```
  date serial_number      ...       smart_197_raw  smart_198_raw
15    2018-01-01      S30075JX      ...                   0              0
509   2018-01-02      S30075JX      ...                   0              0
1000  2018-01-03      S30075JX      ...                   0              0
1488  2018-01-04      S30075JX      ...                   0              0
1975  2018-01-05      S30075JX      ...                   0              0
```

[5 rows x 16 columns]

hdd.columns:

```
    'date','capacity_bytes','serial_number','model','failure','smart_5_raw','smart_197_raw','smart_187_raw',
                'smart_7_raw','smart_1_raw','smart_3_raw','smart_9_raw','smart_194_raw','smart_189_raw',
                'smart_188_raw','smart_198_raw'
```

`temp_samples = hdd[hdd['serial_number']==serial_number]`.

the result of `print(temp_samples.shape)` is like this:

```
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(2, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(61, 16)
(89, 16)
(90, 16)
(89, 16)
(89, 16)
(13, 16)
(40, 16)
(36, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(32, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(68, 16)
(90, 16)
(57, 16)
(7, 16)
(4, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(27, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(50, 16)
(35, 16)
(90, 16)
(89, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(22, 16)
(49, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(88, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(88, 16)
(44, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(89, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(16, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(86, 16)
(90, 16)
(24, 16)
(76, 16)
(36, 16)
(90, 16)
(83, 16)
(66, 16)
(50, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(73, 16)
(90, 16)
(52, 16)
(3, 16)
(90, 16)
(6, 16)
(23, 16)
(43, 16)
(42, 16)
(52, 16)
(25, 16)
(20, 16)
(11, 16)
(52, 16)
(83, 16)
(8, 16)
(34, 16)
(90, 16)
(64, 16)
(52, 16)
(90, 16)
(52, 16)
(71, 16)
(90, 16)
(28, 16)
(37, 16)
(15, 16)
(88, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(80, 16)
(90, 16)
(26, 16)
(90, 16)
(89, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(3, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(82, 16)
(90, 16)
(37, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(68, 16)
(10, 16)
(12, 16)
(90, 16)
(16, 16)
(1, 16)
(43, 16)
(1, 16)
(7, 16)
```

the res of seq_cols:

```
['smart_187_raw', 'failure', 'smart_5_raw', 'smart_197_raw', 'smart_194_raw', 'capacity_bytes', 'smart_7_raw', 'smart_3_raw', 'smart_189_raw', 'smart_198_raw', 'smart_9_raw', 'smart_188_raw', 'smart_1_raw']
```

the value of seq_length is 90

Comment: `list(a_generator)` will produce a list from a generator.

Comment: Is `hdd` a dataframe? If so, there may be a better way to do this

Comment: @cricket_007  hdd is a dataframe

Comment: @Stephen Rauch this I can not get the data.I only get an empty list.for example:[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to get full data from generator (not iterating by values from it), you can convert it to list.**

Change this line:

```
temp = gen_sequence(hdd[hdd['serial_number']==serial_number], sequence_length, sequence_cols)
```

To this:

```
temp = list(gen_sequence(hdd[hdd['serial_number']==serial_number], sequence_length, sequence_cols))
```

Comment: this I can not get the data.I only get an empty list.for example:[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

Comment: I think you need to check the input into `gen_sequence` function. For example `hdd[hdd['serial_number']==serial_number]` might be an empty dataframe. Without some example of your data we can't reproduce your problem unfortunately. Please add an example of your dataframe (`hdd`).

Comment: temp_smaples = hdd[hdd['serial_number']==serial_number].and then the shape of temp_samples is like this:(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(2, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(90, 16)
(61, 16).   And this is the result of print(hdd.head(5)):                                  
              date serial_number      ...       smart_197_raw  smart_198_raw
15    2018-01-01      S30075JX      ...                   0              0
509   2018-01-02      S30075JX      ...                   0              0
1000  2018-01-03      S30075JX      ...                   0              0

Comment: @ Teoretic thanks a lot. I have edited the problem.I added the question you asked.

Comment: Also can you please add `sequence_length` and `sequence_cols` variable values?

Comment: @user7727210 what is your expected output (in `seq_gen`)?

Comment: a 3D array for lstm @Teoretic